# Terminate called throwing an exception(lldb

Tags: iphone, memory

I am working on an iPhone app in `objective C` and whenever I try to run it I get a memory issue in the output "terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)"
Then it points to the main function   `return UIApplicationMain`

I've tried commenting out code that i've recently added but it still gives me this error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `Enable zombies objects`, add breakpoint for `objc_exception_throw` and check what is causing crash.

Comment: I switched from deployment target iphone 6 to iphone 5 and I guess that's the problem. I'm on Xcode version 4.6.2. Do I need an earlier version in order for me to run my code?